# EFCore: Blazor Wasm Update passing property values and Id only?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, http-put

I want to update an entity in a Blazor Wasm app via a Blazor Server Controller. Yes I can just Put the updated entity. But is it possible to just pass the entity Id and the updated property value?

Comment: It might be. But, show the code you are trying.

Comment: As per UpdateActivityTask(int ActivityId, string newTask) and UpdateActivityHelper(int ActivityId, Helper helper)  in HelperService in the mirrored project that the Blazor Service only.  I have ported most of the HelperService  in EFBlazorBasics to EFBlazorBasics_WASM but not these two. 
HelperService: https://github.com/djaus2/EFBlazorBasics/blob/master/Data/HelperService.cs
Server Repo: https://github.com/djaus2/EFBlazorBasics 
Wasm Repo: https://github.com/djaus2/EFBlazorBasics_Wasm